# in my mysql query where not correctly working

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have 8 tables in my database and I need to have all necessary data in one query from them. 
When not using a `where` statement, my query is working, but when I use `LIKE` and `OR LIKE` in my query, the `where` statement is not correctly working

My original query is:

```
SELECT `mhr_patients`.`id`, 
`mhr_patients`.`fullName`, 
`mhr_patients`.`nationalCode`, 
`mhr_patients`.`age`, 
`mhr_patients`.`firstGCS`, 
`mhr_patients`.`fileNumber`, 
`mhr_patients`.`isUnKnown`, 
`mhr_patients`.`docDetail`, 
`mhr_patients`.`presentation`, 
`mhr_patients`.`appRegisterTime`, 
`mhr_patients`.`inspectorRegisterTime`, 
`mhr_patients`.`patientStatusDetail`, 
`mhr_patients`.`patientDetail`, 
`mhr_patients`.`status`, 
`docT`.`text` AS docText, 
`tolOp`.`name` AS tolOpName, 
`tolOp`.`color` AS tolOpColor, 
`tolOp`.`res1` AS tolOpTextColor, 
`pLog`.`breathing`, 
`pLog`.`bodyMovement`, 
`pLog`.`faceMovement`, 
`pLog`.`gag`, 
`pLog`.`cough`, 
`pLog`.`cornea`, 
`pLog`.`pupil`, 
`pLog`.`dollEye`, 
`pLog`.`secondGCS`, 
`pLog`.`sedation`, 
`pLog`.`inspector`, 
`pLog`.`status` As pLogStatus, 
`pLog`.`section`, 
`pLog`.`id` AS pLogId, 
`pLog`.`typeOfSection`, 
`pLog`.`lastUpdateTime`, 
`pLog`.`isTransfer`, 
`pLog`.`opu`, 
`hos`.`name` AS hosName, 
`mhr_opu`.`name` AS opuName, 
`mhr_opu`.`id` AS opuId, 
`mhr_states`.`name` AS cityName, 
`mhr_inspectors`.`name` AS insName 
FROM (`mhr_patients`) 
JOIN `mhr_doc` AS docT ON `docT`.`id` = `mhr_patients`.`doc` 
JOIN `mhr_tol_options` AS tolOp ON `tolOp`.`id` = `mhr_patients`.`patientStatus` 
JOIN `mhr_patients_log` AS pLog ON `pLog`.`pId` = `mhr_patients`.`id` AND pLog.id = (SELECT MAX(mhr_patients_log.id) FROM mhr_patients_log WHERE mhr_patients_log.pId = mhr_patients.id) 
JOIN `mhr_hospitals` AS hos ON `hos`.`id` = `pLog`.`hospital` 
JOIN `mhr_opu` ON `mhr_opu`.`id` = `pLog`.`opu` 
JOIN `mhr_states` ON `mhr_states`.`id` = `pLog`.`city` 
JOIN `mhr_inspectors` ON `mhr_inspectors`.`id` = `pLog`.`inspector` 
WHERE 
`mhr_patients`.`status` =  5 
GROUP BY `pLog`.`pId` 
ORDER BY `mhr_patients`.`inspectorRegisterTime` asc 
LIMIT 30
```

When I use the query above, the result is correct and when I change `mhr_patients`.`status`, a different result is returned, 
but when I use the following query `mhr_patients`.`status` is not working and gives one result no matter what parameter

```
SELECT `mhr_patients`.`id`, 
`mhr_patients`.`fullName`, 
`mhr_patients`.`nationalCode`, 
`mhr_patients`.`age`, 
`mhr_patients`.`firstGCS`, 
`mhr_patients`.`fileNumber`, 
`mhr_patients`.`isUnKnown`, 
`mhr_patients`.`docDetail`, 
`mhr_patients`.`presentation`, 
`mhr_patients`.`appRegisterTime`, 
`mhr_patients`.`inspectorRegisterTime`, 
`mhr_patients`.`patientStatusDetail`, 
`mhr_patients`.`patientDetail`, 
`mhr_patients`.`status`, 
`docT`.`text` AS docText, 
`tolOp`.`name` AS tolOpName, 
`tolOp`.`color` AS tolOpColor, 
`tolOp`.`res1` AS tolOpTextColor, 
`pLog`.`breathing`, 
`pLog`.`bodyMovement`, 
`pLog`.`faceMovement`, 
`pLog`.`gag`, 
`pLog`.`cough`, 
`pLog`.`cornea`, 
`pLog`.`pupil`, 
`pLog`.`dollEye`, 
`pLog`.`secondGCS`, 
`pLog`.`sedation`, 
`pLog`.`inspector`, 
`pLog`.`status` As pLogStatus, 
`pLog`.`section`, 
`pLog`.`id` AS pLogId, 
`pLog`.`typeOfSection`, 
`pLog`.`lastUpdateTime`, 
`pLog`.`isTransfer`, 
`pLog`.`opu`, 
`hos`.`name` AS hosName, 
`mhr_opu`.`name` AS opuName, 
`mhr_opu`.`id` AS opuId, 
`mhr_states`.`name` AS cityName, 
`mhr_inspectors`.`name` AS insName 
FROM (`mhr_patients`) 
JOIN `mhr_doc` AS docT ON `docT`.`id` = `mhr_patients`.`doc` 
JOIN `mhr_tol_options` AS tolOp ON `tolOp`.`id` = `mhr_patients`.`patientStatus` 
JOIN `mhr_patients_log` AS pLog ON `pLog`.`pId` = `mhr_patients`.`id` AND pLog.id = (SELECT MAX(mhr_patients_log.id) FROM mhr_patients_log WHERE mhr_patients_log.pId = mhr_patients.id) 
JOIN `mhr_hospitals` AS hos ON `hos`.`id` = `pLog`.`hospital` 
JOIN `mhr_opu` ON `mhr_opu`.`id` = `pLog`.`opu` 
JOIN `mhr_states` ON `mhr_states`.`id` = `pLog`.`city` 
JOIN `mhr_inspectors` ON `mhr_inspectors`.`id` = `pLog`.`inspector` 
WHERE 
`mhr_patients`.`status` =  5 
AND `mhr_patients`.`fullName`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`nationalCode`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`fileNumber`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`age`  LIKE 'aaa' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`firstGCS`  LIKE 'aaa' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`patientDetail`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
GROUP BY `pLog`.`pId` 
ORDER BY `mhr_patients`.`inspectorRegisterTime` asc 
LIMIT 30
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `and` and `or` in your query.  This will basically negate your where statement.  You need to use parenthesis to group your logic

```
WHERE 
`mhr_patients`.`status` =  5 
AND 

(`mhr_patients`.`fullName`  LIKE '%aaa%'
OR  `mhr_patients`.`nationalCode`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`fileNumber`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`age`  LIKE 'aaa' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`firstGCS`  LIKE 'aaa' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`patientDetail`  LIKE '%aaa%' )
GROUP BY `pLog`.`pId` 
ORDER BY `mhr_patients`.`inspectorRegisterTime` asc 
LIMIT 30
```

You likely intended to have all patients with status of 5 and a either full name like %aaaa% or nationalCode like %aaa$, etc.  To accomplish this, you need to use parenthesis to group your or statements together into a single unit.

Comment: it's working, thanks... It was not on my mind
but a little question, i use codeigniter and for like i use $this->db->like(); from active record so how i add ( & ) to my query?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know codeiginiter.  That's a different question.  Don't forget to mark this as an answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended:

```
`mhr_patients`.`status` =  5 
AND (`mhr_patients`.`fullName`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
    ^ -- bracket here
OR  `mhr_patients`.`nationalCode`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`fileNumber`  LIKE '%aaa%' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`age`  LIKE 'aaa' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`firstGCS`  LIKE 'aaa' 
OR  `mhr_patients`.`patientDetail`  LIKE '%aaa%' ) <-- close here
```

You want `status = 5 or a textual match`. Without the brackets MySQL interprets as `statsus = 5 or textual match in fullName, or other textual match`.

Comment: it's working, thanks... It was not on my mind
but a little question, i use codeigniter and for like i use $this->db->like(); from active record so how i add ( & ) to my query?